# Campo / tabla de Promocion o descuento en SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde llevo ventas de productos, a los cuales quiero agregarles descuentos o promociones en un cierto periodo de tiempo, alguien me podría dar una idea?.

**Ejemplo: día de la semana -> Plancha = costo $5000**

**sábado y Domingo descuento del 20%**

no se como agregar esas promociones en mi base de datos.

Comment: no sabes como hacer que cosa? la tabla? la logica? los calculos? asi como esta, la pregunta es basada en opiniones.. intentaste algo y no funciono??

Comment: Explicate mejor